# Externally detecting user's owncloud session

Tags: php, session, authentication, external, owncloud

I have two websites running on the same server, the first is an owncloud server, the second a site built from scratch. The second site will only be accessible to users currently logged into their owncloud account, but I'm struggling to get the public lib working for me. What I have so far.

```
<?php
   require_once '/var/www/owncloud9/html/lib/base.php';
   require_once '/var/www/owncloud9/html/lib/public/user.php';

    if ( \OCP\User::isLoggedIn() )
        echo( "Hi ".\OCP\User::getDisplayName()."\n" );
    else
        echo( "You are not logged in.\n");
?>
```

The result is always "You are not logged in" even though that is not the case. How do I get the second site to detect the user's owncloud session?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add some comments, like in https://github.com/pbek/qownnotesapi/blob/develop/controller/noteapicontroller.php.

```
/**
 * Returns information about the ownCloud server
 *
 * @NoAdminRequired
 * @NoCSRFRequired
 * @CORS
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getAppInfo() {
    $appManager = \OC::$server->getAppManager();
    $versionsAppEnabled = $appManager->isEnabledForUser('files_versions');
    $trashAppEnabled = $appManager->isEnabledForUser('files_trashbin');
    $notesPathExists = false;
    $notesPath = $this->request->getParam( "notes_path", "" );
    // check if notes path exists
    if ($notesPath !== "")
    {
        $notesPath = "/files" . (string)$notesPath;
        $view = new \OC\Files\View('/' . $this->user);
        $notesPathExists = $view->is_dir($notesPath);
    }
    return [
        "versions_app" => $versionsAppEnabled,
        "trash_app" => $trashAppEnabled,
        "versioning" => true,
        "app_version" => \OC::$server->getConfig()->getAppValue('qownnotesapi', 'installed_version'),
        "server_version" => \OC::$server->getSystemConfig()->getValue('version'),
        "notes_path_exists" => $notesPathExists,
    ];
}
```

`@NoAdminRequired` and `@NoCSRFRequired` in the comments above the method turn off security checks.
(see: https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/developer_manual/app/tutorial.html)

If you now make to your requests with simple auth it should work.
Example: https://user:password@your-server/path/to/your/controller

I do that for example in `OwnCloudService::checkAppInfo` at https://github.com/pbek/QOwnNotes/blob/develop/src/services/owncloudservice.cpp#L322

Comment: Adding in the comments returned the same result

Comment: Can you please post / show the code you are using on both sites, @dsol828.

Comment: This is all the code I have. The code posted above is on the external site, and I have touched nothing in the owncloud9 install.

Comment: I'm sorry, you cannot share the same browser session over different websites, if that's what you are doing. You would need to login again from your other site.
See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery